# How to create a 2D numpy array from a block of strings

Tags: python, numpy

With list comprehension, I am able to take a 20x20 block of numbers in string format, and convert it to a list of lists of integers. The numbers are seperated by white space and the lines are seperated by a newline.

```
grid = [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in nums.split('\n')]
```

However, what I want is to use numpy for its speed. I could use np.asarray() with my intermediate list, but I don't think that is efficient use of numpy.

I also tried using `np.fromstring()`, but I can't figure out the logic to make it work for a 2D array.

**Is there any way to accomplish this task without the use of creating intermediate python lists?**

Comment: The `numpy` `csv` loaders, `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` operate as you do - read each line and from that make a list of lists.  Then at the end create an array from that.  We use `np.array(list_of_lists)` all the time, at least for small(er) arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`np.fromstring`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) setting a space as separator and `reshape` to the desired shape:

```
np.fromstring(s, sep=' ').reshape(20, 20)
```

---

Or as a more general solution:

```
rows = s.count('\n') + 1
np.fromstring(s, sep=' ').reshape(-1, rows)
```

Comment: excellent! I was afraid that wouldn't be able to handle the newlines, but it seems to ignore them.

Answer (score 3):

More general for any 2D grid:

```
rows = s.count('\n') + 1
np.fromstring(s, sep=' ').reshape(rows, -1)
```

Comment: What does the -1 argument mean? I can't find it's use in documentation.

Comment: It simply means that we want numpy to figure out the required dimension. For example, if you have a 2D array `x` of shape `(3, 4)` and you do `x.reshape(-1)` then you will get a 1D array of size 12 (numpy will figure out that this should contains `3x4 = 12` elements).

Comment: @rocksNwaves It was wrong before as the rows and cols where flipped. Now it is correct.